# Detect touch in UIImageView in UIScrollView

Tags: iphone, iphone-sdk-3.0, uiscrollview, uiimageview, touch

i have  images in my UIScrollview which is added in View.
plz go through my code-

```
@interface ScrollViewController : UIScrollView <UIScrollViewDelegate>{

    UIImageView *productImage;
    UILabel *productName;
    NSArray *productArray;
}
@property(nonatomic,retain) UIImageView *productImage;
@property(nonatomic,retain) UILabel *productName;
@property(nonatomic,retain) NSArray *productArray;

- (id)initWitProducts:(NSArray*)_data;
*.m*

- (id)initWitProducts:(NSArray *)_data
    if ((self = [super init])){
         productArray=[[NSArray alloc]initWithArray:_data];       
         [self setFrame:CGRectMake(0, 0, 320, 480)];
         int countList=[self.productArray count];
         self.contentSize=CGSizeMake(320, 585);


        for(int i=0;i<countList;i++)
        {

            productImage=[[UIImageView alloc]initWithImage:[UIImage imageNamed:[[productArray objectAtIndex:i]objectForKey:@"ProductImage"]]];

            productImage.frame=CGRectMake(95, 35+i*125, 100, 100);
            [productImage setUserInteractionEnabled:YES];
            [self addSubview:productImage];
        }
       return self;     
    }


 -(void)touchesBegan:(NSSet *)touches withEvent:(UIEvent*)event
 {
     if([[touches anyObject]view]==self.productImage)
     NSlog(@"Image Touched");
}
```

This is working well but only for last image in Array
the touchesBegan is not working for other images in Array
what should i add here to detect the touch on all the images(1st,2nd,...etc) of Array

Answer (score 0):

You know all the positions of images on UIScrollview, so you can touch position on scrollView into images position in you array.
And another point - you should never compare objective-c objects using "==", always use "isEqual" method instead.

Comment: sorry..but i did't got your clue.

Answer (score 0):

That is because you keep on updating the variable productImage, change your code to read

```
   UIImageView *imageInstance=[[UIImageView alloc]initWithImage:[UIImage imageNamed:[[productArray objectAtIndex:i]objectForKey:@"ProductImage"]]];
    imageInstance.frame=CGRectMake(95, 35+i*125, 100, 100);
    [imageInstance setUserInteractionEnabled:YES];
    [self addSubview:imageInstance];
```